# Get selected user story from a rallygrid

Tags: javascript, rally

I am working with the following code:

```
launch: function() {
    Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
        type: 'UserStory',
        success: function(model) {
            this.down('#gridContainer').add({
                xtype: 'rallygrid',
                model: model,
                columnCfgs: [
                    {
                        text: 'ID',
                        dataIndex: 'FormattedID',
                        width: 75
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Name',
                        dataIndex: 'Name',
                        width: 500,
                        listeners: {
                            click: this._showTasks,
                            scope: this
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        },
        scope: this
    });
}
```

The function _showTasks is called when the user clicks a User Story from the grid but I am having trouble getting the ID of the User Story they clicked. If I *console.log(this)* I can see the ID is stored in an array of items called *selected* but I'm not certain on the path to this property. I was also under the impression that there might be a simpler way to get the most recently selected User Story from the grid?

The end goal is to list all the tasks that are children of the selected user story, either in another rallygrid, or just printing them out directly to the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than registering a click handler on the column you should be able to register a select handler on the grid:

```
{
    xtype: 'rallygrid',
    //...
    //more grid config
    //...
    listeners: {
        select: this._onSelect,
        scope: this
    }        
}
```

And then in your onSelect handler you have the record:

```
_onSelect: function(rowModel, record, rowIndex, options) {
    var id = record.get('ObjectID');
}
```